# How to use nested variables in useState, split over various functions?

Tags: reactjs

I'm lost in creating a part of my application, which results in me having a couple of questions.
I have a JSON string from an API as input for my application. This JSON string needs to create multiple input fields on my page, and I then want to use these inputs to create a new JSON string to submit again.

The JSON string I recieve looks like this:

```
{                                    // For the ruleset values I want to create an input
  oid: 1,
  name: 'my ruleset',
  rules:                             // For each rule I want to create a table row
  [{
    oid: 1,                          // For each field of each rule I want to create an input
    name: 'my rule',
    sequence: 1
  },
  {
    oid: 2,
    name: 'my second rule',
    sequence: 2
  }]
}
```

I thought I was on my way to a solution, but I was very far off. I'm new to React and was trying to use hooks in classes. This looked like this:

```
export default class NewRuleset extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      rulesetOid : '',
      name: '',
      rules: [{
        oid: '',
        sequence: '',
        name: '',
      }]
    }
  }

  GetRulesetData = () => {
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(null);
    const [items, setItems] = useState(null);
    const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();
    
    useEffect(() => {
      fetch("https://myapi.com/api/rulesets/" + searchParams.get("rulesetOid"))
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(
          // Result and error handling
        )
    }, [searchParams]);
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <Row className="mb-3">
            <Col>
              <label htmlFor="RulesetName" className="control-label">Name Ruleset</label>
              <input id="RulsetName" className="form-control" type="text" onChange={this.handleRulesetNameChange}></input> 
            </Col>
          </Row>
          <Row>
            <Col>
              <Table columns={this.columns} data={this.GetRulesetData()} values={this.state} />
            </Col>
          </Row>
          <Row>
            <Col>
              <Button type="submit">Save</Button>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Form>
    )
  }
}
```

Obviously, this doesn't work.
I've been trying to reformat everything to only use functions and have been thinking about the following design:

```
export default function NewRuleset() {
  // Returns:
    // Ruleset input fields
    // Table with rows. Should use RuleRow.
      // Rows should be added dynamically, based on the amount of Rules in the JSON input
}
function RuleRow() {
  // Returns:
    // Table row with inputs. Should use RuleInput to get the input fields
}
function RuleInput() {
  // Returns:
    // Input field
}
```

function `NewRuleset` now looks like this:

```
export default function NewRuleset() {
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(null);
  const [items, setItems] = useState(null);
  const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();

  const [RulesetName, setRulesetName] = useState('');
  const [RulesetOid, setRulesetOid] = useState('');
  const [EngineOid, setEngineOid] = useState('');
  const [EngineName, setEngineName] = useState('');
  const [ProcessOid, setProcessOid] = useState('');
  const [ProcessName, setProcessName] = useState('');
  const [Rules, setRules] = useState([{ rule: Rule}]);  // What to do here?

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://bert.apps.nonprod02.ap.cbsp.nl/api/rulesets/" + searchParams.get("rulesetOid"))
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setItems(result);
        },
        (error) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setError(error);
        }
      )
  }, [searchParams]);

return (
    <>
    <Row className="header">
      <Col>
        <h1>Regelset aanmaken/wijzigen</h1>
      </Col>
    </Row>
      <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <Row className="mb-3">
          <Col>
            <label htmlFor="RulesetName" className="control-label">Naam Regelset</label>
            <input id="RulsetName" className="form-control" type="text" onChange={this.handleRulesetNameChange}></input> 
          </Col>
          <Col>
            <label htmlFor="ProcessOid" className="control-label">Proces</label>
            <Select name="ProcessOid" className="form-control-select" options={this.ProcessOptions} onChange={this.handleProcessChange}/>
          </Col>
          <Col>
            <label htmlFor="EngineOid" className="control-label">Engine</label>
            <Select name="EngineOid" className="form-control-select" options={this.EngineOptions} onChange={this.handleEngineChange}/>
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <Table columns={this.columns} data={this.GetRulesetData()} values={this.state} />
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <Button type="submit">Opslaan</Button>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Form>
    </>
  )
}
```

And here is `GetRulesetData`

```
function GetRulesetData() {
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(null);
  const [items, setItems] = useState(null);
  const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();
    
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("myapi.com/api/rulesets/" + searchParams.get("rulesetOid"))
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setItems(result);
        },
        (error) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setError(error);
        }
      )
  }, [searchParams]);
}
```

My biggest questions are:

- How can I use nested states? (See comment at useState of the `NewRuleset` function.
- Can this be done with functions and classes?
- Generally: Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to answer your questions in order:

#### How can I use nested states

If I understand correctly, your question can be reworded as "How can I use nested properties in state?", so that you have an object which can contain arrays and other objects. You can use objects in state without doing anything special, like `const [obj, setObj] = useState(whatever)`.
For instance, let's say you have a todo list app, you can simply do

```
const [obj, setObj] = useState({ todos: [] });

return <button onClick={() => setObj({ todos: [...obj.todos, obj.todos.lentgh] }) />
```

With this, everytime you click on the button, the length of the current `obj.todos` will be appended to `todos`, so `obj` will become `{  todos: [0] }`, then `{ todos: [0, 1] }` etc...

The key here is to destructure some properties of the object you're updating.

#### Can this be done with functions in classes

Absolutely

#### Are you on the right track

Probably. Basically, to make `useState` work with an array (let's call it `myArray`, that would be initialize as `const [myArray, setMyArray] = useState([])`, you will generally need a combination of:

- to display content, `myArray.map(el => <ComponentWithElementAsProps el={el} />`
- to remove elements, `setMyArray(myArray.filter(el => condition(el))`, where the condition allows you to know what to remove
- to append to the array, `setMyArray([...myArray, newElement])`
- to edit the array `setMyArray(myArray.map(el => condition(el) ? transformation(el) : el))` where `condition` allows you to look up the element to update and `transformation` is the transformation applied to it